# difference between WILL, BE GOING TO and the present continuous

Tags: present-continuous, will-would, will-vs-going-to

when we can use WILL, BE GOING TO or the present continuous.
and what is the difference between situations we use each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** The source cited misses actual distinctions between **going to** and **will**, and posits differences that don't obtain.

I'm putting this response in an answer because I don't know where else to put it. I compliment the OP for citing a source for answers, but one must take care to select those sources carefully. The author of the grammar book in question and the website referenced teaches English as a foreign language at a Hungarian University. His on-line credentials in English, which are over 20 years old, are limited to the masters degree level and do not include studies in the linguistics or history of English. I infer that he is not a native speaker.

I don't find many of the claims plausible, and there are no references to back them up. For instance:

> - We do not use will for things we decided before
>     we're going to movies on Saturday. Do you want to come with us? (not we will go)

To the contrary, I find no obstacle to the following:

> Here are our plans: we will go to the movies on Saturday and to the beach on Sunday. Do you want to come with us?

I don't understand the claim that

> **Will** (future simple) is used to make predictions that are based on personal judgment, opinion or intuition:

To some extent, every prediction is based on personal judgment, opinion, or intuition. The example given is

> I'm sure you'll have a lovely time in Italy. (opinion)

But that opinion could as well be expressed with

> I'm sure you're going to have a lovely time in Italy. (also opinion)

Here's another claim:

> ***Be going to*** is used to make predictions that are based on present evidence. The predicted event is either very near (and can be seen) or seems sure to happen....

Or not:

> Some day intergalactic aliens **are going to** visit Earth.

Consider the following claim with example:

> **Be going to** refers to future intentions that have been decided but have not been fully planned:
>   We're going to get married. (referring to a past decision)

First of all, this could only be true for the present tense: "we are going to get married." In the past futurate -- "we were going to get married" -- you could well have fully-planned future intentions that were dashed. Secondly, "going to" is perfectly acceptable for future intentions that have been fully planned:

> We've paid the deposits on the banquet hall, and we are going to get married even if the levee breaks.

The OP's source says

> note that we use the simple present for schedules, programs, trains, buses, etc:

and that's true, but the present futurate is not restricted to regular schedules. It's fine in the following conversation:

> Mary: What are your plans?
>   Alice: Next month John and I get married and then go on a two-week honeymoon in Uzbekistan.

The *Oxford Modern English Grammar* by Bas Aarts notes that *be going to* and *will* are "[v]ery often interchangeable, though not always." In conditional clauses *going to* appears where *will* cannot:

> If I'm **going to** pass the class, I have to study.
>   ***** If I **will** pass the class, I have to study.

In certain expression of volition, *will* is appropriate, but not *going to*:

> If they **will** not get out of the way, honk your horn.
>   ***** If they are not going to get out of the way, honk your horn.

Comment: This "If they will not get out of the way, honk your horn." really blew up my mind after learning that "we never use "if" after "will", never ever".

Answer (score 1):

**WILL and BE GOING TO for future intentions:**
***Will*** (future simple) is used to express future intentions that are decided at the time of speaking (spontaneous offers, promises, and decisions):

> Come on, I'll help you with those bags. (seeing that someone is struggling with their shopping bags)

- We do not use will for things we decided before

> we're going to movies on Saturday. Do you want to come with us? (not we will go)

***Be going*** to is used to express future intentions that have already been decided before the time of speaking:

> (past) I decided to do it =====> (now) I'm going to do it =====> (future) ...

***I'm going to do something*** = I have decided to do it; my intention is to do it

> I can't make it on Saturday. I'm going to help my parents around the
>   house. (referring to a decision that the speaker has made in the past)

**WILL and BE GOING TO for predictions:**

***Will*** (future simple) is used to make predictions that are based on personal judgment, opinion or intuition:

> I'm sure you'll have a lovely time in Italy. (opinion)

***Be going to*** is used to make predictions that are based on present evidence. The predicted event is either very near (and can be seen) or seems sure to happen:
***something is going to happen*** = we can see now that it is sure to happen

> My sister's going to have a baby. (we can see that she is pregnant)

**BE GOING TO and present continuous for future plans:**

***Be going to*** refers to future intentions that have been decided but have not been fully planned:

> We're going to get married. (referring to a past decision)

***The present continuous*** tense refers to fixed future events and emphasizes that plans or arrangements have already been made:

> We are getting married next month. (the wedding has already been arranged)

note that we use the simple present for schedules, programs, trains, buses, etc:

> our plane arrives in New York at 7:30 tomorrow morning.
>   What time does the movie end tonight?

references: [grammaring](https://www.grammaring.com/the-difference-between-will-be-going-to-and-the-present-continuous-for-future-events) and grammar in use book

Comment: Why are you answering your own question? Anyway, it's an over-generalisation to say _We do not use will for things we decided before_.

Comment: @KateBunting actually I was reading a grammar book, I was wondering when can I use each of these structures. so I searched it and note them down, I thought would be helpful to write them here so if someone else has the same question could use it. I would appreciate that if you improve this answer or write a more general one. thank you :)

Comment: I was taught that **will** expresses resolution ("I will" in the marriage ceremony) and **shall** prediction - "If I don't hurry I shall be late". Oddly, when used with _you_ it's the other way round. "Cinderella, you shall go to the ball." "If you don't hurry, you will be late."